# Resuming from suspend does not work in Linux running on Dell Inspiron 1018

Tags: linux, laptop, gentoo, suspend

**UPD:** I have tried to suspend from live Linux Mint 17.3 XFCE. The symptoms were exactly the same: the system did not wake up.

I am running

```
$ uname -a
Linux inspiron 4.1.15-gentoo-r1 #2 SMP Thu Feb 11 08:49:44 MSK 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N455 @ 1.66GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

I have installed

```
$ eix upower -I
[I] sys-power/upower-pm-utils
     Available versions:  0.9.23-r2 {+introspection ios KERNEL="FreeBSD linux"}
     Installed versions:  0.9.23-r2(22:45:14 25/02/2016)(introspection -ios KERNEL="linux -FreeBSD")
     Homepage:            http://upower.freedesktop.org/
     Description:         The upstream upower 0.9 git branch for use with sys-power/pm-utils
```

When I request the system to suspend, it works: the HDD stops making noise, the screen turns off and the power indicator starts slowly fading in and out, just like it did on Windows. However, when I try to resume, the screen doesn't turn back on. The HDD does fire up again and the power indicator reverts to being constantly on.

In order to debug this, I copied over a version of `/var/log` before the suspend, then I suspended, attempted a resume, and when it failed I shut down the machine by holding the power button for 5 seconds. Then I booted into a live system from a USB stick and copied over an updated `/var/log`. Here is the diff between the two versions:

```
diff log1/messages log2/messages
10354a10355,10380
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: wlp7s0: deauthenticating from ec:43:f6:04:63:00 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron NetworkManager[1960]: <info>  sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron NetworkManager[1960]: <info>  sleeping...
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron NetworkManager[1960]: <info>  (wlp7s0): device state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [100 10 37]
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron NetworkManager[1960]: <info>  (wlp7s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2025
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron NetworkManager[1960]: <info>  (wlp7s0): DHCPv4 state changed bound -> done
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron NetworkManager[1960]: <info>  NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: rtl8192ce:rtl92ce_get_hw_reg():<0-0> switch case not processed
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: rtl8192c_common:rtl92c_firmware_selfreset(): 8051 reset fail.
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz, 92000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron kernel: cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron NetworkManager[1960]: <warn>  Failed to GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.NotConnected: This interface is not connected: disconnect.
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron dbus[1936]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron dbus[1936]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
> Feb 28 11:39:06 inspiron nm-dispatcher[2740]: Dispatching action 'down' for wlp7s0
diff log1/pm-powersave.log log2/pm-powersave.log
703a704,746
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/disable_wol false:
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/disable_wol false: not applicable.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave false:
> Setting power savings for snd_hda_intel to 0...Done.
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave false: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode false:
> Laptop mode disabled.
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode false: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false:
> Setting Host Bridge 0000:00:00.0 to on
> Setting Audio device 0000:00:1b.0 to on
> Setting Ethernet device 0000:05:00.0 to on
> Setting Wireless device 0000:07:00.0 to on
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/pcie_aspm false:
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/pcie_aspm: line 9: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/pcie_aspm false: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/sata_alpm false:
> Setting SATA ALPM on host0 to max_performance...Done.
> Setting SATA ALPM on host1 to max_performance...Done.
> Setting SATA ALPM on host2 to max_performance...Done.
> Setting SATA ALPM on host3 to max_performance...Done.
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/sata_alpm false: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false:
> **sched policy powersave OFF
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth false:
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth false: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false:
> Turning powersave for wlp7s0 off...Done.
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/xfs_buffer false:
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/power.d/xfs_buffer false: not applicable.
> 
diff log1/pm-suspend.log log2/pm-suspend.log
295a296,354
> Initial commandline parameters: 
> Blacklisting 01grub.
> Blacklisting 90clock.
> Sun Feb 28 11:39:06 MSK 2016: Running hooks for suspend.
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
> Linux inspiron 4.1.15-gentoo-r1 #2 SMP Thu Feb 11 08:49:44 MSK 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N455 @ 1.66GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
> Module                  Size  Used by
> snd_hda_codec_realtek    58416  1
> snd_hda_codec_generic    53967  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
> rtl8192ce              71279  0
> snd_hda_intel          18165  2
> snd_hda_controller     15635  1 snd_hda_intel
> snd_hda_codec          70339  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
> snd_hwdep               5794  1 snd_hda_codec
> rtl_pci                29756  1 rtl8192ce
> snd_hda_core           16463  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_controller
> snd_pcm                79924  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
> rtl8192c_common        55680  1 rtl8192ce
> r8169                  68816  0
> rtlwifi                80372  3 rtl_pci,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192ce
> snd_timer              18498  1 snd_pcm
> snd                    56880  10 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
>               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
> Mem:        2041172      390684      887028       59576      763460     1547464
> Swap:       4194300           0     4194300
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:
> Blacklisting 01grub.
> Blacklisting 90clock.
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/01grub suspend suspend:
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/01grub suspend suspend: disabled.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend:
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend:
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend:
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend: disabled.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: not applicable.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
> Kernel modesetting video driver detected, not using quirks.
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.
> 
> Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
> kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
> /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.
> 
> Sun Feb 28 11:39:08 MSK 2016: performing suspend
```

I don't see anything suspicious in it, with the exception that it doesn't seem to contain *anything* about the resume.

The Gentoo Wiki [mentions](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Suspend_and_hibernate#Can_not_resume_after_suspend) that "disabling the security chip in BIOS" may help, but I don't seem to have any setting in BIOS saying anything about "security chips".

What could be the problem and how could I fix it?

**UPD:** following the comment by @rindeal, here is my graphics driver:

```
$ eix intel -I
[I] x11-drivers/xf86-video-intel
     Available versions:  ~*2.9.1 2.21.15 2.99.917-r2 ~2.99.917_p20160218 ~2.99.917_p20160224 {debug dri (+)dri3 glamor +sna +udev uxa xvmc}
     Installed versions:  2.99.917-r2(05:31:32 05/02/2016)(dri sna udev -debug -uxa -xvmc)
     Homepage:            http://xorg.freedesktop.org/
     Description:         X.Org driver for Intel cards
```

Comment: This is a common problem with graphics cards, which are not woken up properly. Your case is kinda weird as your laptop has no dedicated GPU and the chipset is produced by Intel, which usually has good opensource drivers.

Comment: @Pastafarianist  have you found a fix for this issue?  I've been facing a very similar issue with my Inspiron 5558.

Comment: @SuperScript I have installed Manjaro (Xfce edition) and despite the fact that power management is still broken in numerous ways (random freezes on shutdown, screen is solid black color after closing the lid and waiting for a while, tty1-6 don't work), suspend & resume does work. Usually.